# Confused on how memory is allocated

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I am watching a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxCxB2aNouA) on pointers and memory and I'm confused because I thought memory addresses are 1 byte but in the video he is saying they are 32-bits (4 bytes) and that if we had `int a = 2` it would be stored in one memory address, but wouldn't an integer be stored across 4 separate memory addresses since they are a maximum 4 bytes long?

Comment: The video specifically said that he's simplifying, and pretending that addresses point to 32-bit data.

Comment: @DavidRanieri i mean the data stored at the memory address is one byte

Comment: To begin with, you are mixing up addresses with data sizes. The items stored at each address is 1 byte large on all normal computers. The address itself can however be 16, 32 or 64 bits long, depending on the _address bus width_ of the system. Larger data types can of course be allocated across multiple bytes but that doesn't have anything  to do with memory addresses. Also, please stop watching crappy youtube videos and read a book instead. Any random person can make a youtube video, but publishers don't let any random person publish a book, so the quality of content difference is vast.

Comment: @Lundin what books

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer points to a single byte. When you're storing something larger than a byte, it's spread across multiple consecutive bytes, and the pointer points to the first of these bytes. The compiled code uses instructions that can read and write multiple bytes from memory to process the whole thing.

So you're correct, a 32-bit integer will be stored in 4 separate (but consecutive) memory locations.

This is why we have to declare the types of pointers in C. When you derefence the pointer, the type is used to determine how many bytes to read or write starting at that address.

Comment: So on a 32-bit system, there are 2^32 different addressable memory addresses (in theory,  but I assume some are reserved by the OS itself) each storing one byte each, and that's why 32-bit OSes are limited to using 4GB of RAM, because there's only that many memory addresses that the CPU can address?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.